# Shortcut to a Number on Keyboard, but not Numpad

Tags: texstudio

I'd like to have this effect:

1. When I press the button "6" on Keyboard my macro puts "^"
2. When I press the button "6" on Numpad I type "6"

Is it possible to achieve this effect in TexStudio?

I've tried to type 6 for command shortcut, but then I lost the ability to type "6" on both buttons. So I'm wondering if TexStudio can distinguish those buttons (Keyboard 6 vs Numpad 6)?